# K8s local Persistent Volume on Docker Desktop loses data after Docker Desktop restart

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volume, docker-desktop, persistent-volumes

I have problem with PersistentVolume in local K8s cluster. When I am rebooting PC or close and open Desktop Docker I lose data in my PV.

This is my PV config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pvolume
  labels:
    name: pvolume
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Is there any possibility to keep data and not use external PV provider like GCP volume?

**SOLUTION:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pvolume
  labels:
   name: pvolume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: your-local-storage-class-name
  local:
    path: /c/yourDir
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - docker-desktop
```

Comment: Did you take a look https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023#issuecomment-753536143 https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023#issuecomment-772989137 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in links I have provided in comment section - read more: [docker-desktop-pv](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023#issuecomment-753536143), [docker-desktop-pv-local](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023#issuecomment-772989137) - solution/workaround is to use different volume type.  Change  [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume to local. Your [PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) yaml file should look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pvolume
  labels:
    name: pvolume
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /c/yourDirectory
```

`local.path` shows directly where you reference the Windows folder so that you can connect the PersistentVolume locally on a Windows machine.

> - [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)-  HostPath volume (for single node testing only; WILL NOT WORK in a multi-node cluster; consider using  `local`  volume instead)
>   ...
> - [`local`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) - local storage devices mounted on nodes.

See: [types-of-pv](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes).

Comment: Wiktor, yes. Małgorzata's links helped me. I filled up my question with solution. @Malgorzata `nodeAffinity` is required with `local`. But yes, `local` is an answer.